Server booting into Rescue Mode after Ubuntu upgrade (OVH Dedicated Server)
I recently upgraded my OVH dedicated server from Ubuntu 22 to Ubuntu 24.  Now every time the server restarts, it enters rescue mode. OVH sends me an email saying:
“The server has been started in Linux rescue mode. This is because you or a technician has requested this restart as part of an intervention on your server. [...]”
The server boots into a basic Linux system over the network (rescue mode), but the actual OS on the server won’t load.
GRUB config:
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="nomodeset iommu=pt console=tty0 console=ttyS1,115200n8"
GRUB_TERMINAL="console serial"
GRUB_SERIAL_COMMAND="serial --unit=1 --speed=115200 --parity=no --word=8"


Has anyone experienced something similar after upgrading their Ubuntu server?
Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!
